# Não consigo utilizar acentuações no Code Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

Olá! Eu tenho um código:

```
include stdio.h>
include locale.h>

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
printf("Agora não tem mais problema algum para utilizar acentuação!\n");
return 0;
}
```

Configurado direitinho... Mas não retorna com os caracteres acentuados devidos.
Se eu utilizar o DEV C++ ele fica certo.

Eu configurei o GNC CC Compiler no início.

Comment: E qual é a configuração da codificação do editor do CodeBlocks?

Comment: estranho, acho que ele não esta compilando com a flag responsavel por isso tente setala manualmete

Comment: A a codificação no CodeBlocks aparece em `Settings > Editor > Encoding Settings`

Comment: Seu Windows está em Português?

Answer (score 1):

Teste desta forma sem colocar portuguese.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
printf("Agora não tem mais problema algum para utilizar acentuação!\n");
return 0;
}
```

[image: teste]

Comment: Já tentei desse jeito e não funcionou também.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <locale.h>

int main(void){

 setlocale (LC_ALL, "Portuguese_Brazil");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Esses includes tão sem # e sem o sinal de <, devia ser:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

void main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
}
```